# how do you sort out a 2-dimensional array like this one here? i need to remove duplicates and have the duplicates values add to eachother

Tags: python

total_list = [['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Graphite', 2], ['Ammonium', 4], ['Hydrogen', 2]]

in this list each sub list has a substance and its ammount.
for example could it go from:
['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1]
to
['Argon', 2], ['Hematite', 2], ['Organic', 1]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should give a code snippet that can be copied, a clear question and your tries to solve the problem.

Comment: `[[g, sum(i[1] for i in l)] for g, l in groupby(sorted(total_list), itemgetter(0))]`. Imports: [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `collections.Counter` to sum the amount and list the items:

```
from collections import Counter

total_list = [['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Graphite', 2], ['Ammonium', 4], ['Hydrogen', 2]]


result = Counter()
for substance, amount in total_list:
    result[substance] += amount
list(map(list, result.items()))
```

Edit:

Just realized, that the best object for your task could actually be the `collections.Counter`. So instead of `defaultdict(int)` use `Counter`. The advantage of this data type is that you are able to add and subtract different counters (and more, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter for more information). You could use it as follows:

```
substances_a = Counter({"Argon", 3, "Organic": 2})
substances_b = Counter({"Organic": 1, "Hematite": 2})

mixture_ab = substances_a + substances_b
```

which should result in `Counter({"Argon": 3, "Organic": 3, "Hematite": 2})`.
I hope this helps you to work better with your data structure.

Comment: The required output is a list of lists. This produces a list of 2-tuples

Comment: good point, well... the steps are in your answer, so let me add an esoteric one-liner for that last step ;-).

Answer (score 1):

There's often an esoteric one-liner to do this kind of thing but it may be more instructive to show a step-wise approach. Use an intermediate dictionary as a totaliser then build an output list from there. Something like this:

```
total_list = [['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Graphite', 2], ['Ammonium', 4], ['Hydrogen', 2]]

dict_ = {}

for k, v in total_list:
    dict_[k] = dict_.get(k, 0) + v

new_list = [[k, v] for k, v in dict_.items()]

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Argon', 2], ['Hematite', 2], ['Organic', 2], ['Graphite', 2], ['Ammonium', 4], ['Hydrogen', 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

not the most elegant way but it should work:

```
total_list = [['Argon', 1], ['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Argon', 1], 
['Hematite', 1], ['Organic', 1], ['Graphite', 2], ['Ammonium', 4], 
['Hydrogen', 2]]

elements = set([el[0] for el in total_list]) # eliminates repetitions
res = []
for el in elements:
    summ = 0
    for sub_list in total_list:
        if el == sub_list[0]:
            summ += sub_list[1]
    res.append([el, summ])

return res # if you need to return it in a method/function
```

Comment: This works but is remarkably inefficient due to the inner *for* loop. For this small set of data the line *if el == sub_list[0]:* will be executed 54 times